# jquery fadein addClass

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to apply a class to an element on hover i.e. `addClass('active')`

The class adds a border and changes the background color but i would like to have these changes faded in as opposed to just on or off.

Is this possible using jQuery i.e. to add a class and have the effects that the class adds to be faded in?

Comment: CSS3 transitions or use jQuery UI to animate colors.

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery UI [.addClass](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass](http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/).

```
$(function() {
    $("div.className").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("active", 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).removeClass("active", 100);
    });    
});
```

You can also use .animate to get the desired effect. See below,

note you will need [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this to work.

```
$(function() {
    $("div.className").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"
        }, 800);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        }, 800);
    });

});
```

Comment: Note that `.animate` will not animate colors without the UI or at least the [jQuery.color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/blob/master/jquery.color.js) module.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQueryUI this will be built in http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/ if not, what I would do is extract all the attributes from the class and animate them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one good solution if the `.animate()` function is not good for you ('cause you have image background or something).

Create a `div` element with same content and new class. Position the new `div` over your element, and `fade in` it.